# Fully unmount volume?

Tags: terminal, trash, eject

I created a volume in disk utility, and called "projects.dmg".  I assigned a password to it, and stored it in my home directory.  All is good.   I can now mount this volume in terminal, using "cd /users/me; open projects.dmg".   The volume asks for a password and then mounts the volume on my desktop.  GOOD.
I can then use it, and all is well.  When I want to unmount it,  I issue the command "umount /Volumes/projects", and it disappears from the desktop.  Looks good too.

HERE is the issue...  When  I want to mount this volume in terminal again, using "cd /users/me; open projects.dmg".   The volume mounts on my desktop, WITHOUT asking for a password!

I want it to ask for the password again.   I assume my umount command isn't correct..  How do I get the volume to act like I put it in the trash, so it will ask for a password when I mount it again??? Help?

Comment: OH MY!  it worked!!   Diskutil was the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @user3439894 You should write that up as an answer so that this can be marked as solved

Comment: @Ezekiel Elin, Done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to ask for the *password* again, assuming it hasn't been stored in your **Keychain**, you need to *eject* the *disk image*, e.g.:

```
 diskutil eject projects
```

BTW, the *disk image* is mounted at `/Volumes/` not the **Desktop**. (In **Terminal**, run the `mount` command.) It just gives access to it from the icon on the Desktop